# Flutter building an overlay showing up on the right side but can be stacked on top of each other and also close itself

Tags: flutter

i have this screen its a tablet and full of staff

[image]

i need to create an overlay that show up on right side on the screen almost take %30 of the screen so i can show some sort of notifications in there. also there will be buttons and when this buttons were pressed the overlay gonna dismissed and also this overlay should be able to stack up on top of each others. İ'm not sharing my code because its irrelavent. this notifications should work indipendently.

[tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751245/how-to-close-self-overlayentry-ontap)

but raise an errors.
clearly somethings has changed since.

Answer (score -1):

with some adjustment on what you had tried i think i got some solutions

```
Future<void> showCustomNotification({
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    OverlayEntry? overlayEntry;  //nullable
    OverlayState? overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (c) {
        return Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 80,
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Container(
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        overlayEntry!.remove(); //non nullable
                      },
                      child: Text("close")),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    overlayState.insert(overlayEntry);
  }
```

Comment: that actually worked.  i still  have some problems to solve with it but thanks for your effort.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).